# chart.js data from multiple sources and dealing with inconsistencies

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm playing around with visualising some data from an IoT device and the main data for the graph is from the device and is in one single nosql table.

The x axis is the timestamps from the nosql.

The x axis and amount of data is consistent. if there is 100 timestamps returned then there is always 100 points of data across a number of measurements.

This main data is in 15 min intervals.

Now I want to add data from a completely different source and the data is in 5 min intervals. Im going to have 3 times more data from this source and simply pushing the timestamps from that source and then sorting the array that contains the x axis data is going to mess the graph up as the newer data will extend the graph and the main data will sit at the left side of the graph as I'm just using .push to fill up the various arrays.

I'm thinking I may have to somehow look at removing every 2nd item of data from the second source so we end up with the same number of items in the chart datasets.

There could well be better approaches of course.

Anyone dealt with this particular problem before and got any tips? I could maybe iterate over the larger set of data and use a for() and increment i variable by 3 to skip over some data I think

Thanks 
Mark

Comment: Are you trying to merge the data and ultimately plot 1 line (dataset) or do you want to plot a line for each dataset (2 lines)…

Comment: So sorry for late reply Jordan

Its plotline for each dataset (2lines) 

I've figured it out for now by skipping thru the larger dataset so it matches the number of items in the smaller dataset

Comment: Sounds like a good approach.  Good luck!